# How to create a redirecting domain?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

This post is just to learn something, Recently I came across a domain called as **www.content-queen.me/PtWkz** in a page from facebook.com, on clicking the post with this link it redirected me another domain **http://www.wittyfeed.com/story/18644/when-9-cops-sat-down-at-red-robin-the-waitress-realized-something-is-terribly-wrong?utm_source=undefined&utm_medium=SOCIAL&utm_campaign=33-campaign&utm_hash=PtWkz&i=2**...Initially I dint see it, but the next time I did with another url, the same thing happened..so my question is how to do it, I know how create a redirect, as it can be done in .htaccess, but this kind of redirect is very new and interesting, And I even tried to dissect the code and found this source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>When 9 Cops Sat Down At Red Robin, The Waitress Realized Something Is Terribly Wrong</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="When 9 Cops Sat Down At Red Robin, The Waitress Realized Something Is Terribly Wrong" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="You never know when any deed doneÂ by you can make anyone's day. Hence, being on the good side of the threshold is always preferable. Jessica Dunbar definitely understands the effect good actions have and she is definitely doing everything the right way. Especially, when it is about men in uniform.Â When she notices a group of cops sitting in her section, this happens." />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.content-queen.me/PtWkz" />


    <meta property="og:image" content="http://cdn.wf-media.com/18644/pvoaelaw7buvswooe47x.jpeg" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="www.content-queen.me" />


    <meta property="article:section" content="Pictures" />


    <a href="https://www.viral9.com/tr_hs_vs/PtWkz" id='myLink'></a>


    <style type="text/css">
      #myLink {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>

      </head>

    <body>
<div id="output">


</div>


    </body>
</html>


<script type="text/javascript">


 // view_count_update();


function view_count_update()
      { 
        var jUTM = "utm_source=SOURCE&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=CAMPAIGN&utm_hash=HASH";

               var redirect_url = "http://www.wittyfeed.com/story/18644/when-9-cops-sat-down-at-red-robin-the-waitress-realized-something-is-terribly-wrong?utm_source=SOURCE&utm_medium=SOCIAL&utm_campaign=33-campaign&utm_hash=PtWkz&i=2";
               redirect_url = redirect_url.replace("SOURCE", document.referrer.split('/')[2]);
               window.location = redirect_url;    
      }


    function myFunc(){

    }



    //hello
</script>

<script>
  try{
    (function(){
      var d = {
          'user_id'       : "33",
          'url_id'        : "2609257" ,
          'advertiser_id' : "1",
          'user_agent'    : navigator.userAgent,
          'campaign_id'   : "18362" ,
      }
      $.ajax({ 
          url: "http://www.asapoo.com/mysql_testing",
          type:'GET',
          data: d,
          success : function(data) {view_count_update();},
          error   : function(){ view_count_update();},
          complete: function() {view_count_update();},
          timeout : 2000 
        });

    })();  
  }catch(e){ view_count_update(); }
</script>


<script src="//c.fqtag.com/tag/implement-r.js?org=T6tuwESp3TrUwruYu4eZ&p=NOTSET&a=33&cmp=PtWkz&rt=display&sl=1&fmt=banner&ctu=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wittyfeed.com%2Fstory%2F18644%2Fwhen-9-cops-sat-down-at-red-robin-the-waitress-realized-something-is-terribly-wrong%3Futm_source%3DSOURCE%26utm_medium%3DSOCIAL%26utm_campaign%3D33-campaign%26utm_hash%3DPtWkz%26i%3D2&fq=1"></script>
```

I hope there will be guys who would have done this here and would like to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

That code is pretty much it, really. The redirects are coming from a site set up just for that. It most likely has a database driving it, mapping those random strings of letters to sites. Then it had a template for the page you posted here where it fills in values from the database.

You can see in the code where it updates a page view counter. Then, right after that it sets `window.location` to where they want you to go, which makes the browser load the page.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a url shortener, you need a back-end script to do the redirect.

The application works as follows, when a request for [www.content-queen.me/PtWkz](http://www.content-queen.me/PtWkz), it will analyze the url. and take the random string **PtWkz** as a key, this key is connected to the orginal url and the relation stored somewhere in database or cache memory.

What the script do is to match the short string to the orginal url and send to our browser http redirect 302.

There are some feathers to the shortener like you can change the destination **the original** url with keep sharing the short url.

The back-end script can be written in all programing languages and scripts, you may use python or php for it.

There are many online url shortener services like **goo.gl** and **bitly.com**.